# Nodejs error handling in callback (xml-stream)

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

i use the xml-stream library for nodejs to parse a big xml file. That works very well.
But i notice, that if there is a problem like a RefereceError in the callback of a xml-stream event, nodejs is only quitting without notify me or throw an error.

A short example is the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var XmlStream = require('xml-stream');

var stream = fs.createReadStream('E:/jdown2/dblp/dblp.xml');
var xml = new XmlStream(stream);


xml.on('endElement: article', function (data) {
    console.log("article"); // works well
    var demo = functionThatNotExists(data);
    console.log("nodejs exit before this console log");
});
```

So my question is, how can i reach it, that nodejs tells me that there was an error and where the error occur?

Or does xml-stream not providing that?

In a normal callback function like:

```
errorInCallback("test", function (err,data) {
    console.log(err, data)
});

function errorInCallback(data, cb) {
    var demo = functionThatNotExists(data);
    var err = null;
    return cb(err, demo)
}
```

all works like expected and nodejs throws a *ReferenceError*

Does someone can explain me the reason and maybe how to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a handler for the `error` event:

```
xml.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But sadly this doesn't work. i added the event listener for error. But its not fire or notify. It only quits node

Comment: Hmmm.. maybe you can try listening for uncaught exception in the node process? Maybe the issue is not in xml-stream. `process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception) { console.log(exception); });`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call a function that doesn't exist with the data you are getting from `xml.on` ? If so, the error is coming from there and then so you should handle it.

```
var fs = require('fs');
    var XmlStream = require('xml-stream');

var stream = fs.createReadStream('E:/jdown2/dblp/dblp.xml');
var xml = new XmlStream(stream);

xml.on('endElement: article', function (data) {
    console.log("article"); // works well
    try {
       var demo = functionThatNotExists(data);
       if (demo == null) {
         throw new Error('Something went wrong');
       }
    } 
    catch(e) {
     console.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
    }

   console.log("nodejs exit before this console log");
  );
```